# cannot get the user details from using uid of the currentUser ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

I tried to get the username of an user by using the uid of the current user. uid is stored in both firebase database and auth. `this.userid=firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
   this.username=firebase.database().ref('Users/'+this.userid+'/username');`
but i cannot get the username of the user instead of the user name it return the url of the username.[this is the result when it run][1]
please can anybody whats the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like you are only passing reference. you should use `on()` or `once()` method to get the value.

Try

```
let userRef = firebase.database().ref('Users/'+this.userid);
userRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  this.username = snapshot.val().username;
});
```

Comment: I add the same code to get the username, then it gives a runtime error saying cannot set property 'username' of null

Comment: still the same result

Comment: what is the result for `console.log(snapshot.val())`?

Comment: i changed `on` method with `once` please try

Comment: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'username' of undefined

Comment: are you sure you have a field `username` under each user?

Comment: I am not sure why, check this official [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once) for more details

Comment: let userRef = firebase.database().ref('Users/'+this.userid);
userRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var username = snapshot.val().username;
  console.log("username"+username);
});

Comment: for var username it working but for this.username its not working

Comment: Try define `username:string;`